# How to use Validating String Parameter Plugin in the Jenkins declarative pipeline code?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm curious as to if it is possible to define the String Validator Plugin in a Jenkins declarative pipeline code? I already have a working setup defined via job UI, but my intention is to put everything in the pipeline defined as:

```
string(name='', ......).
```

Unfortunately, all examples on the web are explaining how to set up the validation in the UI, which I already have. Or is it one of those plugins that is not supported in a pipeline model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This plugin can be used as a `validatingString` parameter in the declarative pipeline code.

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        validatingString(name: "test", defaultValue: "", regex: /^abc-[0-9]+$/, failedValidationMessage: "Validation failed!", description: "ABC")
    }

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                echo "${params.test}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that the first time you will run your pipeline after adding this code, the parameter won't show up - it will be added during the first run of the pipeline. After that you will see the parameter in the pipeline UI:

[image]

And when you run the parameterized pipeline, the validation will be applied:

[image]

Comment: Trying this myself but I'm getting `Invalid parameter type "validatingString"`. Same goes for extendedChoice

Comment: Blue Ocean is not supporting this, Do we have any other way to validate input ?

Comment: @Alistair Hardy make sure that you have installed those Jenkins plugins (for validating string and extended choice) first.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but when I wrapped each of my arguments into a named key, I was able to bypass this error I received:

So this will give you `javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.validatingString() is applicable for argument types` Error:

```
            validatingString (
                "EMAIL_VALIDATED"
                'defaultEmail'
                'someregex',
                'somevalidationfailuremessage',
                'Use your email' 
            )
```

However, this worked:

```
            validatingString {
                name("EMAIL_VALIDATED")
                defaultValue('defaultEmail')
                regex('someregex')
                failedValidationMessage('somevalidationfailuremessage')
                description('Use your email') 
            }
```